# Why do I keep getting ARIMA (0,0,0) for my stock analysis?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, stock, arima

I've been learning about time series forecasting. I downloaded daily stock closing prices for MCD from 2016-2-9 to 2021-2-8. I took the log difference of prices to make sure stationarity. I ran the function auto.arima and got an ARIMA(3,1,2) (this is without approximations) but then I took a test sample from the data (80/20 split)and the auto ARIMA function returned ARIMA(0,0,0). I was confused with this.

Then I tried IBM stock from 2005-2-10 to 2021-2-10 and this had the same issue. When I take the training set, the ARIMA returned (0,0,0). Can someone please tell me what's going on and how I can use this to forecast. [This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxeUl.png)